# joint probability in sum

Tags: probability

Sorry for naive question,

Why the following is true:

$\sum_{x,y}^{}p(x,y) \log p(x) = \sum_{x}^{}p(x) \log p(x)$

I don'r understand why actually

$\sum_{x,y}^{}p(x,y) = \sum_{x}^{}p(x) $

Explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read $\sum_{x,y}p\left(x,y\right)$ as $\sum_{x}\sum_{y}p\left(x,y\right)$.

Then: $$\sum_{x,y}p\left(x,y\right)=\sum_{x}\sum_{y}p\left(x,y\right)=\sum_{x}p\left(x\right)$$
as a consequence of: $$\sum_{y}p\left(x,y\right)=p\left(x\right)$$

Application on $\sum_{x,y}p\left(x,y\right)\log p\left(x\right)$ gives:
 $$\sum_{x,y}p\left(x,y\right)\log p\left(x\right)=\sum_{x}\log p\left(x\right)\sum_{y}p\left(x,y\right)=\sum_{x}\log p\left(x\right)\times p\left(x\right)$$